# Codeblock Beginning error

Tags: c, gcc

I have been learning `c++` in `Dc++` for 1 month. I installed `codeblock 13.12` 2 days ago for c. I had a problem this moment.

I progressed new project --> console application --> c --> name and folder etc.
I clicked main.c in source-workspace on left frame.

It's okay but when I click build&run to classic printf"Hello World" codeblock gives me a information message which say that:

```
"it seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build now"
```

If I click yes it gives me an error message:

```
------------- Build: Debug in cdfg (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)--------------- 
mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\cdfg.exe obj\Debug\main.o 
mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2) 
Please submit a full bug report. 
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions. 
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

If I click no it gives me an empty black exe file.

I've tried to solve this for hours but I couldn't. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: "Please submit a full bug report. See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions." - what happened when you carried out this step?

Comment: Don't add the word "solved" to the title. To indicate that the problem is solved, accept an answer by clicking the check mark. (You might have to wait a while before doing that.)

Comment: Sorry I won't repeat this wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. 
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

At first in site,whose link above, i had downloaded **codeblocks-13.12-setup.exe** file and i get error. After then i downloaded **codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe** and it is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I had DevC++ installed along with Code::Blocks, whic resulted in the above error while building. After uninstalling DevC++ the issue got resolved.

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all **download MinGW**: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJndz.png)
2. Double click the **mingw-set-up.exe** and press **Install**.

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz5Jf.png)
3. **Dont change** the installation directory and press **Continue**

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boOGj.png)
4. **Wait** until installed...

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WCnJ.png)
5. Then press **Continue and wait** again.
6. **Mark all files** for installation

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtq08.png)
7. Go: **Intallation --> Apply Changes**. Press again **Apply** and **wait** the download package.

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNvtB.png)
8. Press **"Close dialogue automatically,.."** and **wait**...

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65efE.png)
9. You can close MinGW.
10. Copy the addres of new MinGW bin file which should be `C:\MinGW\bin`
11. Right click on your **start** and press **System**
12. Press **Advanced system settings**--> **Environment variable**

    [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr2sL.png)
    [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ1oK.png)
13. In **System variables** click **Path** and then **Edit**.

    [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pCEO.png)
14. Then press **New** and paste the addres of file "bin" that is inside of file MinGW in Documents(step 10) that should be `C:\MinGW\bin`. Then press OK-->OK-->OK.

    [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQmFF.png)
15. Open **cmd**. I mean: right click on your start and press "Command Prompt". Write `g++ --version` and press enter. [If it's like this you don't have problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a52LH.png)
16. **Open Codeblocks** go **settings-->Compiler**. **Select** "GNU GCC Compiler".

    [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU9pB.png)
17. Go **Toolchain executales** and fill in the blanks as in the screenshot. Files must be in local disk in `C:\MinGW\bin` chose from there.

    **Caution:** [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JJh0.png) is for 32-bit systems. I'm not sure for 64-Bit systems.
18. **If you have 64-Bit** don't do the 17st step and try if it works. If it's not work, do the 17st step. If it's not work, again try to put files (to "C compiler", "c++ compiler" and to "linker for dynamics li") that have almost the same name as the files that are in screenshot.

***You can write your questions below.***